# How to use AureliaJs into play framework

Tags: javascript, playframework, aurelia

I am integrating **aurelia with play framework**. I have built aurelia and put in into play project and calling index.html page from play routes. but i want to use it with more efficient way. I want to know wheather i am using it in correct way. if not, what is the correct way to do that? this is the link of github repository of the project. https://github.com/knoldus/activator-play-aureliajs

Comment: I have to build and copy it into play project every time when i make any changes into aurelia project.

Comment: I'd like to accomplish something similar. That is pretty much how I imagined it, but you need some kind of development mode that doesn't require you to build it each time. Could you put the aurelia folder inside public/javascripts, and then configure play to use public/javascripts/aurelia while in dev mode, but use public/javascripts/dist while in prod mode?

Comment: Actually no, you would probably want to run play and aurelia (with gulp watch) separately during development. Just make sure they're running on different ports. You don't need to ever call the index route on PlayFramework during development, you just need to build aurelia into the dist folder when you release.

Comment: we can not use _play framework's_ routing in this because aureliaJs is for SPA, which does not re-route the page mostly.